# Can I convert this dynamic SOQL to static SOQL?

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

```
String queryString =
            'SELECT Id,IsPersonAccount,RecordTypeId FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate < ' + 
            Ke.Job_Start_Date_Time__c.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'') +
                'AND RecordTypeID IN (\'' + PersonAccount + '\', \'' + BusinessAccount + '\')';
```

I am learning the difference between static and dynamic SOQL and I am interested to change this query from dynamic to static but I see I cannot do that since static SOQL does not provide INCLUDES. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can continue to use the IN keyword but you need to present it slightly differently with [bind variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm). In fact, in this case, I actually think it makes life easier for you:

```
Set<Id> recordTypeIds = new Set<Id>{PersonAccount,BusinessAccount};
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id,IsPersonAccount,RecordTypeId FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate < :Job_Start_Date_Time__c AND RecordTypeId IN :recordTypesIds];
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like to format the field Job_Start_Date_Time__c as I have stated above and when I do that I get the error as 'Invalid bind expression type of String for column of type Datetime' . Can I not format the field ?

Comment: Would like to suggest take out the Datetime assigning it to a variable e.g. Datetime `dt = Ke.Job_Start_Date_Time__c.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');`  and refer it in where.

Comment: Oh now I get the error as 'Illegal assignment from String to Datetime'

Comment: @user3920709 why do you need to format it first? If both Job_Start_Date_Time__c and LastModifiedDate are Datetime then you wouldn't need to do anything. The error you get when you format it is because you've formatted the datetime to a string and compared it to a datetime (LastModifiedDate)

Comment: You are right, I was mixing things up. Thanks

Comment: @PhilHawthorn Could you please explain why the same comparision with the LastModifiedDate to formatGmt of Job_Start_Date_Time__c  is working in dynamic query but getting the error in the static query ?

Comment: @user3920709 its because in your dynamic query, you're formatting to a string literal in the correct date/time format for the database to understand. In the static query, you'd be converting the DateTime to a String and the compiler is detecting that you are trying to compare a String with a Datetime.